# how to skip ntpdate synchronization during boot on centos

Tags: centos, boot, ntpdate

I moved a centos server to a new IP and now it's stuck on ntpdate synch during boot.
I just need it to boot once so I can assign the new IP.
Going back to the old IP is not an option right now.
CTL C AND CTL D don't work.
Please help.

Comment: Disconnect the network cable?

Comment: tried that already

Comment: nevermind ... long timer ... it finally gave up and continued ... thanks

Comment: I posted an answer that may help if you run into this in the future. Some services will hang forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had this problem with a *nix box (changed IP schemes, old IP was no longer valid) the only way I could get around hanging services at boot time was to start it in single-user mode and hand-modify the interfaces file (specifically `/etc/sysconfig/network/network-scripts/` ..going from memory) then rebooting.

You can boot into single user mode by pressing `e` in grub to modify the run line (the longest one) and adding `single` to the end of it.